# How to round difference of two dates in sql to integer days?

Tags: unix, cgi, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I round off difference of two dates in sql to integer days. Round statement, doesn't exactly work

```
a=15/02/2016; 
b=15/02/2016; 
round((a-b),0); /* output 1 */

a=15/02/2017;
b=23/03/2017;
round((a-b),0); /* output is +36 instead of it being -36 */

round((a-b),0,1); /*and when i used truncate statement like */

                  /* it's throwing an error saying too many arguments*/
```

[1] anyone can help? small code/command is appreciated

Comment: What has this got to do with databases?

Comment: You may need to narrow it down to 1 database brand as things can vary

Comment: Is the question tagged by mysql, sql-server and oracle together?! Specify one database only, please.

Comment: just asking what's the root cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server: `SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2017-03-23','2017-02-15') AS DiffDate`
Returns -36

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`TO_DAYS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) MySQL function:

```
SET @a='2017/02/15';
SET @b='2017/03/23';
SELECT TO_DAYS(@a)-TO_DAYS(@b);
```

To get absolute difference use [`ABS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) function:

```
SELECT ABS(TO_DAYS(@a)-TO_DAYS(@b));
```